# Eclipse Collections - Is there a containsAny() method for Sets?

Tags: java, eclipse-collections

I can't seem to find a `containsAny()` method for `SetIterable` types in Eclipse Collections. Is there one?

```java
MutableSet<String> set1 = Sets.mutable.of("a", "b", "c");
ImmutableSet<String> set2 = Sets.immutable.of("c", "d", "e");

set1.containsAny(set2); // I can't find this method.
```

It's easy enough to write one:

```java
/**
 * True if [set1] contains any element in [set2].
 */
public static <T> boolean intersects(SetIterable<T> set1, SetIterable<? extends T> set2) {
    return set1.intersect(set2).notEmpty();
}
```

But I just wanted to know if one already existed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a containsAny method, but you can do this:

```
set2.anySatisfy(set1::contains);
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods [`containsAny`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/11.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/RichIterable.html#containsAny(java.util.Collection)) and [`containsNone`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/11.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/RichIterable.html#containsNone(java.util.Collection)) were added to the `RichIterable` interface in the Eclipse Collections 11.1 release. There are also methods named [`containsAnyIterable`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/11.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/RichIterable.html#containsAnyIterable(java.lang.Iterable)) and [`containsNoneIterable`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/11.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/RichIterable.html#containsNoneIterable(java.lang.Iterable)) which take `Iterable` as a parameter instead of `Collection`.

The following now works using your code example.

```
MutableSet<String> set1 = Sets.mutable.of("a", "b", "c");
ImmutableSet<String> set2 = Sets.immutable.of("c", "d", "e");
MutableSet<String> set3 = Sets.mutable.of("c", "d", "e");
MutableSet<String> set4 = Sets.mutable.of("d", "e", "f");
ImmutableSet<String> set5 = Sets.immutable.of("d", "e", "f");

Assertions.assertTrue(set1.containsAnyIterable(set2));
Assertions.assertTrue(set1.containsAny(set3));

Assertions.assertFalse(set1.containsAny(set4));
Assertions.assertFalse(set1.containsAnyIterable(set5));

Assertions.assertTrue(set1.containsNone(set4));
Assertions.assertTrue(set1.containsNoneIterable(set5));
```

I used `containsAnyIterable` and `containsNoneIterable` for the `ImmutableSet` examples because `containsAny` and `containsNone` take `java.util.Collection` as a parameter type and `ImmutableSet` does not extend this interface. The `containsAnyIterable` and `containsNoneIteable` methods work with `ImmutableSet` because it does extend `java.lang.Iterable`.